# solving an implicit function at specific points

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to solve an implicit function and write the values to a .txt file

u = 0.5 + sin(x - 0.75*u) for x = [0, 1] and u = [-0.5, 1.5]

I have to get the corresponding u values at specific x points (0 0.1 0.2 0.3... 1.0). is there a way?

Im plotting the implicit function as below

```
bla = ezplot('y - sin(2*pi*x - 0.4*y)');
h = gca
get(h)
tmp = get(bla,'contourMatrix');
h = gca
get(h)
set(gca,'ylim',[-1.0 1.0])
set(gca,'xlim',[0 1.0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpolate using [`interp1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) to find the corresponding Y values for the given X values using `tmp` matrix.

```
XValues = 0:0.1:1;
YValues = interp1(tmp(1,:), tmp(2,:), XValues);
```

The default method of interpolation is `linear`. You can see other possible methods [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#btwp6lt-1-method).

Comment: I have added the code to question. Thank you so much for the help.